# Linux software raid (mdadm) 3-disk RAID5 array, 2 devices "out of date"

Tags: raid, fedora, mdadm

I'm having issues trying to bring back a RAID5 3 disk array, where it seems 2x disks are out of date.

```
root@mindstorm4: mdadm -E /dev/sd[bcd]
/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 6a243319:84b8f9a9:355f027e:58b8a6fb
           Name : md_stripey
  Creation Time : Sun Feb 23 22:08:02 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3907028992 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 3907028992 (3726.03 GiB 4000.80 GB)
    Data Offset : 16 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=160 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 7299f928:b1105a5c:f89d8600:0f944324

    Update Time : Sun Jun  5 09:43:12 2016
       Checksum : efcdeccc - correct
         Events : 4375

         Layout : parity-last
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 6a243319:84b8f9a9:355f027e:58b8a6fb
           Name : md_stripey
  Creation Time : Sun Feb 23 22:08:02 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3907028992 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 3907028992 (3726.03 GiB 4000.80 GB)
    Data Offset : 16 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=160 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f403f8da:b4eec381:fbcf9628:b562ad94

    Update Time : Wed Feb  1 00:15:25 2017
       Checksum : 60f42d25 - correct
         Events : 574913

         Layout : parity-last
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : ..A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 6a243319:84b8f9a9:355f027e:58b8a6fb
           Name : md_stripey
  Creation Time : Sun Feb 23 22:08:02 2014
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 3907028992 (1863.02 GiB 2000.40 GB)
     Array Size : 3907028992 (3726.03 GiB 4000.80 GB)
    Data Offset : 16 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=160 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : a69bf0c5:49d75e40:2ad555a4:fe6d68c3

    Update Time : Wed Feb  1 00:13:22 2017
       Checksum : b504bd62 - correct
         Events : 574909

         Layout : parity-last
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

When I try to activate;

```
root@mindstorm4: mdadm -A --scan -v
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
<snip>
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md/md_stripey_0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md/md_stripey_0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md/md_stripey_0, slot 0.
mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md/md_stripey_0 as 0 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdd to /dev/md/md_stripey_0 as 1 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/sdc to /dev/md/md_stripey_0 as 2
mdadm: /dev/md/md_stripey_0 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array.
mdadm: looking for devices for further assembly
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
```

But, the device file /dev/md/md_stripey_0 does not exist, so I cannot check out the array status using --detail.

Additionally, I'm worried about running `mdadm -A --force ...` because the man page says that this is potentially destructive.

Comment: You actually have ONE drive out of sync, that is `/dev/sdb`, its been out of your raid since June 5th last year. Could you please post output of `mdadm --examine /dev/sdd` and `mdadm --examine /dev/sdc` so we can go ahead and make a right assembly?

Comment: The command I ran and posted above was an examine of all 3 disks - and I noticed sdb was out of sync for a lot longer. I actually managed to reassumeble using --force using `sdc` and `sdd`, but the irritating thing is that while the man page says this is risky, I had no way to quanify what the risk was. I figured it was potentially rolling back to the oldest updated date of the disks (`sdc`) and that risk was worth it. Array back online with no data loss it seems, making backups now.

Comment: Well the potential risk is not about rolling back, there's no way for raid-5 to do any rollback, what you have after --force is a degraded array for which every block you read is calculated on the fly from remaining two drives. If the blocks are out of sync, you will get garbage instead of real block data and what happens next depends on filesystem being used and an offset where corruption occured.

Comment: Hi Peter, EXT4. It's a shame that this risk is not explained in the documentation. I assume now that the filesystem is now subject to some random single block errors, and a safe way forward is a rebuild, using new disks?

Comment: If your filesystem has been mounted with no obvious damage then you should do a backup. After its done you should introduce third drive into the array as spare and let it rebuild. The backup step is very important, because you can't tell if rebuild would succeed before it actually does - there could be some bad sectors on these two drives that could prevent it. Other than that, your two drives were out of sync for 4 blocks written, you can tell that by examining `Events` field in your `mdadm -E` output, that's not that much..

Comment: Thanks Peter. If you make a short answer to this question I'll accept it so that you get the karma. Many thanks for your insightful comments.